# How to define infinite numbers in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, computer-science

When I used `#define INF (1.0/0.0)` to define infinite number, it called the error C2124, which means that a constant expression has a zero denominator. It was told that do not divide by zero can avoid it. But I really need to define inifite number, could someone give a simple way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works in VS, especially such an old version, but [STL has special provision for that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity):

```
double never = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard way is to utilize the function [`std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) in the `<limits>` library.

This is also only meaningful if `std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity` is `true` (which it usually will be).